# About nuclear energy levels

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

The energy level of a heavy atomic nucleus such as that of uranium, which is related to the zeta function, is determined by taking a discrete value, but cannot it be represented by an equation like an electron?

Comment: are you trying to compare a many-body problem with a 2-body problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of an electron around an atom, as in the [Hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html) solutions, the answer  is no, as nuclei are many body objects and also the potentials entering the quantum mechanical solutions are not only electromagnetic ( as in the hydrogen atom) but also the strong nuclear force potential, an attractive spill over potential from the quantum chromodynamics ruling the basic [elementary particles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) .All nuclear matter is made up by protons and neutrons, and in turn [protons and neutrons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/proton.html) are composites of quarks.

There are models, though, that do give a good representation of the energy levels, as the [nuclear shell model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html), as measured in the lab. The [zeta function](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Riemann-Zeta-Function-and-what-are-its-purpose-and-uses) treats the nuclei with large numbers of nucleons statistically. but the shell model gives a good fit to the [periodic table of elements.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model)